# How to use HMC of hybris to check the promotion of specified product?

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I want to see the promotion of some product in HMC, but I do not remember how to entry the promotion section and check the product promotion information.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its in HMC--> Marketing -->Promotions